# What are these stacked panels on the ISS in this image?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object

I found this image of the ISS in a folder on my computer. I don't know the exact source but a reverse image search shows it in many different websites. Unfortunately I can't pin down a date.

What are the stacked flat plates shown in the cropped image?

It seems strange, the middle ones are shielded from space and sunlight by the ones on either side.

Credit is likely NASA, but can't be sure. Here's an undated instance: https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-awards-international-space-station-cargo-transport-contracts

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKsPR.jpg

Comment: @Muze oh that's much better than the previous one! Still, the images in the question are sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are folded-up solar panels on the Russian FGB module ("Zarya"). Folded up so they don't interfere with the truss-mounted radiator panels, and not needed since the large ISS solar arrays were added.

Zarya shortly after launch

[image]

Annotated photo of an early, interestingly asymmetrical ISS assembly stage showing they are solar arrays (PVA = Photo Voltaic Array) and without the truss mounted radiators fully deployed. (TRRJ = Thermal Radiator Rotary Joint) "Foreword" should read "Forward"

[image]

Angle shot that shows how the FGB arrays could interfere with the fully deployed radiators if the solar arrays were still fully extended. (ignore "unity module" callout)

[image]

All photos NASA, annotations from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nazareth_Bedrossian/publication/267365907/figure/fig1/AS:295545433280517@1447474930960/International-Space-Station-Stage-12A1-components.png)

Comment: wow there's a lot going on in that image!

Comment: The original is one of my faves. Note the shuttle robot arm holding the inspection boom under the shuttle belly so the instruments on it are protected from the undocking of the Soyuz from which the picture was taken.

Comment: oh, I found the inspection so interesting I hadn't stopped to wonder where the photo was taken from. I'll give this a more thorough look in the morning...

Comment: [Why do the ISS' Thermal Rotary Radiators need to tilt?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34140/12102)

Comment: Apart from that one panel that isn't @uhoh -- but rejecting most of the energy from the sun still leaves more than enough to impact cooling efficiency

Comment: Do they still produce power?  Would a PV panel be damaged if it were producing power while "unplugged"  ?

Comment: That last image is stunning. Do you know where can I find a full res, unanotated version?

Comment: @FreddieR since NASA burned down all their good websites, it's hard to find, but here you go https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/557307main_iss027e036685_full.jpg It was taken by Paolo Nespoli from a Soyuz during STS-134. The shuttle is Endeavour.