# Why are the big solar panels on the ISS orientated away from the Sun?

Tags: iss, solar-power

While looking at this picture below from another [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34124/what-are-these-stacked-panels-on-the-iss-in-this-image) I notice all the panels are not facing the Sun. Why is that?

[image]